# How to use multiple Python venv in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have a notebook with dual boot, and on Windows I manage my Python packages using conda, and in VS Code select interpreter shows me all my conda env that I built, but on Linux I'm trying to use virtualenv because of a numpy problem with conda.

I'm facing another problem which is I don't know how to make all my envs show on Python select interpreter just like with conda. I know that I can find one of the envs by changing Python path, but I actually have 3 different envs and I would like to select interpreter to show all then and not having to change path every time I want to use a different env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the "official" [*Python extension* (`ms-python.python`)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python) installed?

**It automatically detects known virtual environments at several locations**, as [described in docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments):

> The extension automatically looks for interpreters in the following
>   locations:
>
> - Standard install paths such as `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/sbin`, `c:\\python27`, `c:\\python36`, etc.
> - Virtual environments located directly under the workspace (project) folder.
> - Virtual environments located in the folder identified by the python.venvPath setting (see General settings), which can contain
>     multiple virtual environments. The extension looks for virtual
>     environments in the first-level subfolders of venvPath.
> - Virtual environments located in a ~/.virtualenvs folder for virtualenvwrapper.
> - Interpreters installed by pyenv.
> - A pipenv environment for the workplace folder. If one is found, then no other interpreters are searched for or listed as pipenv
>     expects to manage all aspects.
> - Virtual environments located in the path identified by WORKON_HOME (as used by virtualenvwrapper and pipenv).
> - Conda environments that contain a Python interpreter. VS Code does not show conda environments that don't contain an interpreter.
> - Interpreters installed in a .direnv folder for direnv under the workspace (project) folder.

For example I have my environments (created via `python3 -m venv`) located at `/home/my_username/envs/` directory. For example:

- `/home/my_username/envs/my_project_1/`
- `/home/my_username/envs/my_project_2/`
- `/home/my_username/envs/my_project_2_py36/`
- `/home/my_username/envs/my_project_2_py34/`
- etc.

And **the extension offers them all automatically** when I want to switch environment via the `Python: Select interpreter` command from command palette.

... or, instead of using the command palette, you should be able to use the widget at the bottom of vscode.

[image: vscode virtual env widget]

Comment: Thank you very much. My virutalenvs were saved on a folder called venvs with  python.venvPath pointing to her and in a folder inside the workspace, just like it says on docs to do, but isn't working and I still cant figure why. Anyway, i just changed the folder name to envs and worked out, thank you.

Comment: You explained very well. a followup question is I have many projects under the same working directory, all of them have a venv/bin/python. Now vscode suggested all of them with relative path and same name. Is there a way to distinguish which one I'm selecting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). after installing this on top of the virtualenv.

you will be able to use `workon` command to select different envs you have in the system.

simply enter `workon` to list available envs and then `workon <myenv>` to select it.

Answer (score -1):

To use multiple virtual environments (venvs) in VSCode for Python, you can follow these steps:

**1. Create a virtual environment**:

Use the terminal to create a new virtual environment for your project.
You can do this by running `python -m venv <path_to_venv>`.

**2. Activate the virtual environment** :

After creating the virtual environment, activate it.

On Windows, you'd run `<path_to_venv>\Scripts\activate`

On Unix/Linux, it's usually source `<path_to_venv>/bin/activate`.

**3.Open VSCode**:

Open VSCode and​ navigate to your project directory.

**4. Set interpreter**:

Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the command palette, then type `Python: Select Interpreter` and choose the interpreter corresponding to the virtual environment you created.

**5. Install dependencies**:

Install any dependencies your project needs using `pip install`.

**6. Repeat for each project**: Repeat these steps for each project that requires a separate virtual environment.

By following these steps, you'll be able to work on multiple Python projects in VSCode, each with its own isolated environment.